# Refresh a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have read posts about this but I can't get the right answer.

I have tried Hide and Show to refresh a table:

```
       $("#cmdUnreadID").click(function(){
           $.ajax({
                    type: "GET", 
                    url:"orderBy.php", 
                    data: "unreadCtrl=1", 
                    success:function(result){
                      $("#tableInbox").hide(500,function(){
                        $("#tableInbox").show();
                      });
                    }
            });
       });
```

this does not work for me. I tried other animations as well but nothing works. I think im missing something or I'm using the wrong way.

Any Suggestion how to Refresh the table only?

Comment: do you check that your `success` function works? try `alert('something');` within you `success` function to check.

Comment: What do you mean about Refresh table? reload the data?

Comment: @ijse Yes, I want to refresh the output of the table because the table contains the Sql.

Comment: First step would be to actually populate the table, $('#tableInbox').html(result);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Populate the table with the AJAX content

```
   $("#cmdUnreadID").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
                type: "GET", 
                url:"orderBy.php", 
                data: "unreadCtrl=1", 
                success:function(result){
                  $("#tableInbox").hide(500,function(){
                    $("#tableInbox").html(result).show(); // <-- Notice html() call here, to populate the table
                  });
                }
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are you loading the result data to the UI. Probably you need to set the result to any of the element. use the `html` method to do that

```
success:function(result){
      $("#tableInbox").hide(500,function(){
          $("#tableInbox").html(result).show();
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change/update the content of the `#tableInbox` and to do that you can try this:

```
success:function(result){
     $("#tableInbox").hide(500,function(){
         $("#tableInbox").html(result).show();
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#cmdUnreadID").live('click', function () {
            $("#tableInbox").hide(500);

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "orderBy.php",
                data: "unreadCtrl=1",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#tableInbox").html(result).show();

                    //Or

                    // $("#tableInbox").replaceWith(result).show();
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

i cant see on your code something that really changes the table, 
you gota change the tables .htm() and feed the result like

```
$("#tableInbox").html(result)
```

note: you can also set **dataType:** to "html" or "xml" in your request, because if you receiving XML the result wont be suitable for direct feed to the table .html. jquery will do an inteligent guess from the datatype in servers response, but still it can be XML